# Printing Duplicate Records from the Data View In Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to print all records of a data-view into a file using a for loop in my customization in Acumatica. Unfortunately I am ending up with printing the first record everytime resulting into duplication of records, Unable to track where I am going wrong....Please Assist

Here Goes my Code......

```
public class MayBankGIROProcess : PXGraph<MayBankGIROProcess>
{
        public PXSelect<MayBankGIRO> Document; //This is my Data View
        public PXAction<MayBankGiroFilter> createTextFile;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create Text File")]
        [PXButton()]
        public virtual IEnumerable CreateTextFile(PXAdapter adapter)
        {          
            List<string> myList = new List<string> { };
            foreach (MayBankGIRO dacRecord in this.Document.Select()) //this is the loop which is taking the data records.
            {
                myList.Add(dacRecord.ReordType+ "|"+ dacRecord.CustomerReferenceNumber+ "|"+ dacRecord.ClientBatchID+ "|");
                // The above line is printing only the first record of the data view everytime .
            }

            string filename = "DAWN" + ".txt";
            Download(myList, filename);
            return adapter.Get();
        }

        public static void Download(List<string> lines, string name) //method generating file
        {
            var bytes = default(byte[]);
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }

                stream.Position = 0;
                bytes = stream.ToArray();

                sw.Close();
            };
            PX.SM.FileInfo textDoc = new PX.SM.FileInfo(name, null, bytes);

            if (textDoc != null)
            {
                throw new PXRedirectToFileException(textDoc, true);
            }
            else
            {
                PXTrace.WriteInformation("Could not generate file");
            }
        }
}

[Generated Text File with all duplicate Record][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kllmk.png
[Original Record from database][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbr9k.png
```

Comment: What is the definition of the view Document?  Is there a parent-child relationship in this view, and you are only getting the header document?  Can you generate the list via a normal Generic Inquiry and see the results you are trying to achieve here?  If all of your data should be in the Document view, you could debug and check the results of this.Document.Select() to see if that has the results you expect.

Comment: Hi Stevens, There is no parent child relationship in this view. Its getting data only from one Table (DAC), I have already debuged and checked the result in this.Document.Select(), its genetaring a SQL Query for Selecting all data from the Table, like in the next comment.

Comment: SELECT [ReordType], [CorporateID], [ClientBatchID], [Country], [ValueDate], [DocDate], [FromDate], [ToDate], [ByOrderOf], [CustomerReferenceNumber], 
[DebitReference], [DebitDescription], [TransactionCurrency], [TransactionAmount], [InDebitAccountCurrency], [DebitingCurrency], [DebitAccountNumber], [CreditAccountNumber], [ResidentIndicator], [BenificiaryName1], [ChangesBorneBy]
FROM [MayBankGIRO] [MayBankGIRO]
WHERE ( [MayBankGIRO].[CompanyID] = 2)

The above Query is generated by this.Document.Select()

Comment: As per your suggestion I have created G as well from the Table(DAC), The GI is working fine, its showing all the records from the Table

Comment: Did you figure it out?  I'm not following what would cause this result.

Comment: Hi Brian, I couldn't able to figure out the result.

Comment: could you share the DAC definition?

Comment: Is this a listview page or a form view? If its a form that typically only displays one header record at a time doing the select of the view will only return the current or "top" record. You will instead require an additional select statement within your code.

foreach (MayBankGIRO dacRecord in PXSelect<MayBankGIRO>.Select(this))....

Comment: @Fernando My DAC definition is same as all other Acumatica DAC definition.

using System;
 using PX.Data;
 
 [System.SerializableAttribute()]
 public class MayBankGIRO : PX.Data.IBqlTable
 {
  #region ReordType
  public abstract class reordType : PX.Data.IBqlField
  {
  }
  protected string _ReordType;
  [PXDBString(100, IsUnicode = true)]
  [PXUIField(DisplayName = "ReordType")]
  public virtual string ReordType
  {
   get
   {
    return this._ReordType;
   }
   set
   {
    this._ReordType = value;
   }
  }

Comment: @Fernando I am sharing one field of my DAC.

Comment: Hi Brian I have Shared the Project with you at GitHub, request you to please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Hi @JoshuaVanHoesen i have tried the same, It did not yield desired result. you may share ur GITHub username, I can share the project with you as well.

Comment: Hi @Fernando you may also share your GITHub username, i can share the project with you as well.

Comment: @SDNetsense jvanhoesen

Comment: Hi Joshua Van Hoesen....I have shared the project with you @GITHub, please share your experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when the report is pulling from a SQL View DAC which doesn't have unique key defined. Add IsKey=True on DAC fields until the SQL view is pulling unique record and the error should go away.